# To 'flag' a specific condition in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a result set in the below format and I need to flag "GroupColumn"

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID   GroupColumn         ConditionCol1         ConditionCol2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    101                 ABC                   99
  2    101                 DEF                   99
  3    102                 ABC                   01
  4    102                 DEF                   01
  5    103                 ABC                   02
  6    103                 DEF                   99
  7    104                 DEF                   02
  8    104                 DEF                   99
```

First of the I need to flag the data based on "GroupColumn", with in this "GroupColumn" I am looking to satisfy Condition of "ABC" from one row and "99" from another row but not necessarily from the same row.

I looking to get a final result set some thing like this for the "Output" column

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID   GroupColumn     ConditionCol1     ConditionCol2     Output
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    101             ABC               99                Satisfied 
  2    101             DEF               99                Satisfied
  3    102             ABC               01                
  4    102             DEF               01
  5    103             ABC               02                Satisfied
  6    103             DEF               99                Satisfied
  7    104             DEF               02
  8    104             DEF               99
```

Comment: which dbsm you are using?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when conditioncol1 = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by groupcolumn) > 0 and
                  sum(case when conditioncol2 = 99 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by groupcolumn) > 0 
             then 'Satisfied'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

An alternative is to use `group by`:

```
select t.*, tt.flag
from t join
     (select groupcolumn, 'Satisfied' as flag
      from t
      where conditioncol1 = 'ABC' or conditioncol2 = 99
      group by groupcolumn
      having sum(case when conditioncol1 = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when conditioncol2 = 99 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) tt
     on tt.groupcolumn = t.groupcolumn;
```

Comment: This will still 'flag' the condition true if the conditions are satisfied in the same row with in a "GroupColumn" which I do not want.

Comment: @Prakazz . . . No.  These flag the columns based on the groups defined by the `groupcolumn`.  That is how window functions work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and you need to add Output column to your original table, you can try the following:

```
create table #temp 
(GroupColumn int,ConditionCol1 varchar(20),ConditionCol2 int)

insert into #temp values (100,'ABC',99)
insert into #temp values (100,'DEF',99)
insert into #temp values (101,'ABC',02)
insert into #temp values (101,'DEF',99)
insert into #temp values (102,'DEF',99)
insert into #temp values (102,'DEF',99)

ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD [Output] varchar(10)
GO

;with cte(GroupColumn) as (
   select GroupColumn
   from #temp
   where ConditionCol1 <> 'ABC'
     and ConditionCol2 = 99
)
UPDATE t
SET [Output] = 'Satisfied'
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN cte on t.GroupColumn = cte.GroupColumn
WHERE t.ConditionCol1 = 'ABC'

UPDATE t
SET [Output] = 'Satisfied'
FROM #temp t
WHERE [Output] is null
and t.GroupColumn in (Select GroupColumn from #temp where [Output]='Satisfied')

select * from #temp
```